Bounds on Besov norms for mollification of a bounded Lipschitz function
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, non-empty, regular open domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Let $1\le p,q\le \infty$ and $s>0$.  Let $\mathcal{B}_{p,q}^s(\Omega)$ be the Besov space on $\Omega$ corresponding to these parameters, see eg Triebel's book [1].
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to [-B,B]$ be $L$-Lipschitz for some $B>0$ and let $(\varphi_{\epsilon})_{\epsilon>0}$ be a family of mollifiers.  Can one bound
$$
\|f\star \varphi_{\epsilon}\|_{B_{p,q}^s(\Omega)}
$$
above by a function of $\varepsilon$, $L$, and $B$?
